# python: flatten to a list of lists but no more

Tags: python

I have a list of lists which is nested in multiple layers of lists.

possible inputs:

`[[[[1,2,3] , [a,b,c]]]]` or `[[[1,2,3] , [a,b,c]]]` or `[[[1,2,3]] , [[a,b,c]]]`

when I use `flat()` it will just flatten everything which is not what I want.

`[1,2,3,a,b,c]`

What I need instead is

`[[1,2,3] , [a,b,c]]`

as the final output.

My flat definition is below

```
def flat(S):
    if S == []:
        return S
    if isinstance(S[0], list):
        return flat(S[0]) + flat(S[1:])
    return S[:1] + flat(S[1:])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import collections
def is_listlike(x):
    return isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(x, basestring)

def flat(S):
    result = []
    for item in S:
        if is_listlike(item) and len(item) > 0 and not is_listlike(item[0]):
            result.append(item)
        else:
            result.extend(flat(item))
    return result

tests = [ [[[[1,2,3] , ['a','b','c']]]],
          [[[1,2,3] , ['a','b','c']]],
          [[[1,2,3]] , [['a','b','c']]] ]

for S in tests:
    print(flat(S))
```

yields

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing:

```
if S == []:
    return S
```

with:

```
if (not any([isinstance(x,list) for x in S])) :
    return [] if S==[] else [S]
```

seems to do the trick.

Or:

```
if S == []:
    return S
if (not any([isinstance(x,list) for x in S])) :
    return [S]
```

I see two requirements - detecting when `S` shouldn't be flattened, and then returning a value that won't be flatten when joined with the rest (i.e. join with `append` rather than `extend`).  My guess is that a list of non-list elements should not be flattened.

I'm barking up the same tree as `unutbu`, but in a more confused manner.:)

Answer (score 0):

flat() could become

```
def flat(mylist):
    return[val for sublist in mylist for val in sublist]
```

Then you could call it in a for loop like this

```
while type(mylist[0][0]) is list:
    mylist = flat(my list)
```

and it will reduce it to your desired output regardless of the number of nested lists

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```